# Observer pattern implemented in C# with delegates?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, events, delegates, observer-pattern

There is a question already answered which is [In C#, isn't the observer pattern already implemented using Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034/in-c-isnt-the-observer-pattern-already-implemented-using-events)

It asks if the observer pattern is already implemented in c# using events.

While I get the events and observer pattern, isn't the observer pattern really just delegates and events is a further implementation?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? You seem to be aware of the other question and its answer, so you seem to be asking something in addition to that, but it is unclear to me what it is.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are correct.  An event is simply a delegate with some slightly different functionality.  All of the observer pattern can be implemented with delegates without ever touching the `event` keyword.

You may be interested then, in what the "event" keyword actually brings to the table.

- Events can be part of an interface, whereas
  regular delegate field cannot
- Events cannot be invoked by outside classes,
  but regular delegates can
- Events have additional accessors (add and remove) that you can override and provide custom functionality for

Edit:  [Here's a great writeup](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html) with IL code comparison between events and delegates.  (Hint: it's pretty much the same).

Comment: @womp, regarding your first bullet point, is `Action<T>` not a delegate which can be part of an interface?

Comment: @womp, regarding your first bullet point, is `Action<T>` not a delegate which can be part of an interface? `public interface ITest
    {
        void SupplyCallbackMethod(Action<int> callback);
    }`

Comment: Its interesting that the differences are so delicate that most people dont need to bother with events at all since delegates does everything they need most of the time.